# How to insert a view in the body field of a node?

Tags: views, entities

Is there any way to insert a view in the body field of a node?

Something similar to the [insert](http://drupal.org/project/insert) module for inserting images in the body field.

Comment: Do you want a button like "insert php"?

Comment: I thought of a select list to select the view, then place the cursor in the body and click a button to `insert` the view. Similar to the insert module for images.

Answer (score 4):

I've found this module [Insert View](http://drupal.org/project/insert_view)

I haven't tried yet. Let me know if it fits your request.

I found this as well [Views Reference](http://drupal.org/project/viewreference)
I tested both and I think the second is more appropriated for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
  $viewName = 'view_name_here';
  print views_embed_view($viewName);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

also you may create chainable tokens that will replace a token with view output